# How do you get a pet unicorn?

Tags: terraria

I love unicorns as you can tell but I have no clue how to even get unicorns on the land.

How do i get a pet Unicorn?

Comment: Is there anything that leads you to believe you *can* have a pet unicorn?

Answer (score 5):

I'm going to assume you're talking about the **Unicorn Mount**. This information is readily available on the Terraria wiki, which I have linked to below.

In order to get the Unicorn mount in Terraria, you must acquire the [Blessed Apple](https://terraria.gamepedia.com/Blessed_Apple) mount item from any enemy which exists in the Hallow, which appears once you have entered Hardmode. The Blessed Apple has a 0.5% chance to drop, increased to 0.67% in Expert Mode.

This enemy and item only exist in the desktop version of Terraria.

Comment: FYI: According to the link, Blessed Apples can drop from *any* Hallow enemy.

Comment: Appreciated. I've updated the answer.